# Android/iPhone-like ScrollView for Swing

Tags: java, swing

Is there an android/iphone-like scrollview which can be used in swing applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the various [Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html) to see if you can find anything you like.

Otherwise try searching the web.

Answer (score 0):

Try using different LookAndFeels. It will provide you similar stuffs. For better LookAndFeels search for SkinLookAndFeel. This contains inbuilt Mac theme. Also JGoodies provides some good L&F. To set L&F in your java app write as follow:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new WindowLookAndFeel());

/** Either you provide class instance by using new operator or provide full class name. Both will work. **/
```

[Reference link.](http://www.taranfx.com/best-java-swing-look-and-feel-themes-professional-casual-top-10)